# How to hidden the GroupBox when Select one of radio button in another GroupBox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, desktop-application

GM everybody,

I've work on WinForms using **Vb.net**

I want to hide all components inside the groupbox2 when I checked radio button that inside groupbox1

I need to know what is the name of event and where to select it from radio button or from groupbox

Comment: You want to hide the groupbox itself or leave it there and make it look like an empty square?

Comment: @CaiusJard I want to leave it as an empty square

Comment: "I want to hide all components inside the groupbox2 when I checked radio button that inside groupbox1" When ANY RadioButton in the GroupBox is selected, or when a SPECIFIC RadioButton is selected? Also, if no other controls besides the RadioButtons take focus when the form loads, then at least one RadioButton will automatically get selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the whole groupbox itself:

```
Sub SomeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles SomeRadioButton.CheckedChanged
  GroupBox2.Visible = Not SomeRadioButton.Checked
End Sub
```

If you want to hide the controls inside but leave an empty groupbox:

```
Sub SomeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles SomeRadioButton.CheckedChanged
  GroupBox2.Controls.ToList().ForEach(Function(c) c.Visible = Not SomeRadioButton.Checked)
End Sub
```